# JtextField is not working properly with program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

This is a flashcard program I'm working on. When study button is pressed a word is placed on the middle of the screen and the program is suppose to read from the text field for the user input and print whether it is right or wrong. The problem is that the program is reading the text field after study is pressed so it is printing false before the user can input a answer.

Can someone briefly explain why this is not working and what I can do to fix this issue?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class NoteCardGUI implements ActionListener {

public static JFrame frame;
public static JPanel panel;
public static JLabel label;
private NoteCard ex;
private JButton study;

public static Box box1 = new Box(), box2 = new Box(), box3 = new Box();

public NoteCardGUI() {
ex = new NoteCard("Hello", "World");

frame = new JFrame("Flash Card");
panel = new JPanel();

study = new JButton("Study");


study.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String resp = NoteCard.getResponse(ex);
        String chal = NoteCard.getChallenge(ex);
        String a = text.getText();

        label = new JLabel(chal, label.CENTER);
        label.setAlignmentX(0);
        label.setAlignmentY(0);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.revalidate();

        if(resp.compareTo(a) == 0)
        {
            label = new JLabel("Correct!");
        }
        label = new JLabel("Incorrect");
    }
});

panel.add(study);

frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

new NoteCardGUI();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

This is my NoteCard class for whoever needs to see it.

```
public class NoteCard {

public static String challenge;
public static String response;



public String front;
public String back;


public NoteCard(String front, String back) {

 this.front = front;
 this.back = back; 

 double a = Math.random();
    if (a > 0.5) {
        challenge = front;
    } else
        challenge = back;
    if (a < 0.5) {
        response = front;
    } else
        response = back;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
  //return "The challenge:" + challenge + " " + "The response: " + response;
  return "The Front: " + front + " " + "The Back: " + back;
}

public static String getChallenge(NoteCard a) {
    String chal = a.challenge;
    return chal;
}

public static String getResponse(NoteCard a) {
    String resp = response;
    return resp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NoteCard test = new NoteCard("Ryan", "Hardin");

    System.out.println("The challenge: " + getChallenge(test));
    System.out.println("The response: " + getResponse(test));
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're doing too much with one button. If you must use one button instead of, for example, a "Start Studying" button that is replaced, then check for an empty string before comparing.

Comment: @Ryan Hardin Can you post your codes for NoteCard class? There is no way to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: @user3437460 yeah just give me a second

Comment: @user3437460 I just posted the NoteCard class underneath the GUI class.

Comment: @RyanHardin There are still missing codes. Your NoteCard class is incomplete. Box class is missing as well.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

first you need to place the UI initialization statements(the statements that you create the label and add the label into the frame) outside of the actionPerformed method, 
otherwise your UI will be re-initialized every time you click the buttons

secondly, you are creating a new JLabel when you are actually trying to update the text in the JLabel. this will not work, because you never added the newly created JLabel into the frame. instead do this:

```
label.setText("the message you want to show");
```